# Updating profile with python-twitter

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to update my Profile info via [python-twitter module](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/).

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(username="username", password="password")
>>> user = api.GetUser(user="username")
>>> user.SetLocation('New Location')
```

The problem is that it is not getting updated and the documentation is unclear if there's another step I need to do - is there a "save" that I need to call or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the python-twitter module currently supports updating a profile. SetLocation will only update your local user object that GetUser has returned.

It would be relatively trivial to add support for this to the module though. Have a look at this method:

[account/update_profile](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0update_profile)

and then add a new method to the Api class that calls **account/update_profile** with the updated user data.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the API, just wondering if I was missing something really basic that was preventing me from saving the changes. Clearly not. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

This are the set*profile* methods from User:

```
SetProfileBackgroundColor(self, profile_background_color)

SetProfileBackgroundImageUrl(self, profile_background_image_url)

SetProfileBackgroundTile(self, profile_background_tile)
    Set the boolean flag for whether to tile the profile background image.

    Args:
      profile_background_tile: Boolean flag for whether to tile or not.

SetProfileImageUrl(self, profile_image_url)
    Set the url of the thumbnail of this user.

    Args:
      profile_image_url: The url of the thumbnail of this user

SetProfileLinkColor(self, profile_link_color)

SetProfileSidebarFillColor(self, profile_sidebar_fill_color)

SetProfileTextColor(self, profile_text_color)
```

You can see a list of available methods at http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html

Comment: Junajo - you are not looking deep enough:  SetProfileImageUrl(..) does not issue a remote command, it just sets a data member in the class.  I will be releasing an updated version of the twitter lib at https://github.com/jaytaylor/python-twitter-api which will actually set the profile image url.  I'll try to remember to post back here when I do first public release.  Anticipating it being ready within the next week or so.